# How to Extract Linear Model Parameters from Seaborn lmplot()?

Tags: python, seaborn, linear-regression

Is there a way to extract the parameters of the regression line(s) that `seaborn.lmplot()` fits for a given set of data? I have looked up the documentation and haven't been able to spot anything that would help me in this regard.

Just to be clear, I don't mean the `lmplot()`'s function parameters, but the `m`,
and `b` of `y = mx + b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seaborn uses scipy stats linregress, so you could get it directly from there.

```
from scipy import stats
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df.x,df.y)
```

Comment: Thank you. Technically, the source code uses matrix multiplication using numpy for the case of bare-bones least squares that I was after, but your answer was helpful nevertheless.